# List readonly files

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

I need to list or show or query for the files in a folder (well, technically, on a USB drive, but I can navigate to it in Finder/Terminal) that are marked readonly.

All the Google-fu in the world just reveals solutions to change permissions but I don't need to do that.

My Dashcam marks videos/images readonly to save them when I press the button on it, but they're still in a folder with a few hundred MOV files, and I need a simple way to filter down to the ones I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make use of the `-w` option in bash to check if the file is writable or not.

Go into the directory you want to check your files, then enter:

`for RO in $(find . -type f);do [ -r "$RO" ] && [ ! -w "$RO" ] && echo $RO;done`

(credit to [www.unix.com](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/263414-how-recursively-usr-bin-find-only-readonly-files.html))

**[EDIT]**

To deal with spaces in file names, better to use the `find -exec` way rather than looping into the `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec [ -r {} ] \; -exec [ ! -w {} ] \; -exec echo {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec [ -r {} ] \; -exec [ ! -w {} ] \; -print
```

Comment: Textually parsing the output from `find` usually breaks on file names containing space characters and similar. May not be a problem in the context the OP has, but might hit you in other circumstances.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the head up, I fixed the case replacing the for loop with using `find -exec`

Comment: My (hopefully) last remark on this: `find . -type f -exec [ -r {} -a \! -w {} ] \; -print`, much easier to read than the `find ... | xargs ... sh -c` monstrosity in my own answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -perm +444 \! -perm +222
```

searches for all files (`-type f`) which are readable (`-perm +444`) but not writable (`! +perm +222`).

If your mind boggles after reading up on `-perm` in `man find` you can also use the (significantly slower, especially on slow devices) option of processing the output of `find`yourself:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c '[ -r "$1" -a ! -w "$1" ] && echo "$1"' sh
```

This basically takes each file `find` finds, and runs it through a small shells script to check permissions.

PS: Hey, I didn't say the second way is less mind-boggling :-)

Comment: Although the second method runs slower, it might be more accurate in certain situations if I am not mistaken with this example test for example: `touch test_file; sudo chown root:staff test_file;` (the first method fails to list the file, although it is a read-only file for the user)

Comment: @Yoric There is no general solution for this using `find` alone, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22421/find-a-users-writable-files-and-directories and the original question linked from there. In the case of the OP it's probably not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, my head is spinning right now, so much to learn digging into "simple questions" :)

Answer (score -1):

List the files and grep for the read-only pattern:

`ls -l | grep '^-r--'`

`^` symbol indicates start the line.

We are filtering only files here by mentioning `^-`, after that looking only for read permission files by specifying `r--`. If you want to filter read & executable permission files, you can use `r-x`.

If you want just the filename, you can use below command

`ls -l | grep '^-r--' | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'`

Printing the file name using above command works, only if you don't have spaces in file name.

Comment: Grepping the `ls -l` is a smart way to do it, but beware that your files might start with `-rw-r--r--` with `root` as the owner, and such files won't be listed, even though they aren't writeable for the user.

Comment: `grep ... | awk` is usally not required, the second command can be rewritten as `ls -l | awk '/^-r--/ {print $NF}'`